# Trying to understand a SIGSEGV crash when showing an NSPopover

Tags: swift, cocoa, crash, segmentation-fault, nspopover

I am getting a crash with the following stack trace and I am not sure to understand what is happening and how to fix it:

```
libobjc.A.dylib
objc_release
libobjc.A.dylib
(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*)
CoreFoundation
_CFAutoreleasePoolPop
HIToolbox
ActivateInputMethodInstance
HIToolbox
utOpenActivateSelectedInputMethodInDoc
HIToolbox
utOpenActivateAllSelectedIMInDocIterator
CoreFoundation
CFArrayApplyFunction
HIToolbox
utOpenActivateAllSelectedIMInDoc
HIToolbox
MyActivateTSMDocument
AppKit
-[NSTextInputContext activate]
AppKit
+[NSTextInputContext currentInputContext_withFirstResponderSync:]
AppKit
-[NSTextInputContext invalidateCharacterCoordinates]
AppKit
-[NSTextView(NSSharing) setSelectedRanges:affinity:stillSelecting:]
AppKit
_NSEditTextCellWithOptions
AppKit
-[NSTextFieldCell _selectOrEdit:inView:target:editor:event:start:end:]
AppKit
-[NSCell selectWithFrame:inView:editor:delegate:start:length:]
AppKit
-[NSTextField selectText:]
AppKit
+[NSAppearance _performWithCurrentAppearance:usingBlock:]
AppKit
-[NSTextField selectText:]
AppKit
-[NSTextField becomeFirstResponder]
AppKit
-[NSWindow _realMakeFirstResponder:]
AppKit
-[NSWindow _makeParentWindowHaveFirstResponder:]
AppKit
-[NSWindow _selectFirstKeyView]
AppKit
-[NSWindow _setUpFirstResponder]
AppKit
-[NSWindow _doWindowWillBeVisibleAsSheet:]
AppKit
-[NSWindow _reallyDoOrderWindowAboveOrBelow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:]
AppKit
-[NSWindow _doOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:]
AppKit
NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange
AppKit
-[NSWindow _doOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:]
AppKit
-[NSWindow orderWindow:relativeTo:]
AppKit
_NSWindowRebuildOrderingGroup
AppKit
NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange
AppKit
-[NSWindow addChildWindow:ordered:]
AppKit
-[NSPopover showRelativeToRect:ofView:preferredEdge:]
Slideas
Slideas.Document.togglePresentationParams(sender: __C.NSButton) -> () Document.swift:397
```

where the `Document.swift:397`line is:

```
paramsPopover.show(relativeTo: sender.frame, of: sender, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.maxY)
```

Any idea where I have to start investigations?

Comment: `-[NSTextField selectText:]` is happening. Anything special about the first text field?

Comment: Nothing special. It comes from a NIB file and got a value in `viewDidLoad`